# Chrome OS sudo startunity app

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, operating-systems, shell-script

I am running crouton unity on a Samsung chrome-book.

How do i automate a shell script to start unity into a chrome OS app that I can place on the chrome shelf next to the other chrome apps?

i want to log in to chrome and just have to click the icon to start unity.

Answer (score 0):

There's a ton of requests on crouton's github issues list that are asking for the same and apparently they all have the same answer: it's not possible because of a security limitation around the model that crouton uses to start the chroot (ie: requires root).

I've restarted one of the discussions in https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/369 to entertain other ways of achieving the chrooting such as what ARC/hon does to run an Android chroot for Android apps enabling each app to keep its own Chrome OS shortcut.